# How to sort any generic collection using bubble sort and check if it's sorted?

Tags: java, sorting, generics, bubble-sort

I have to implement a method which sorts any kind of collection by using bubble sort and after that to test if it really is sorted how can I accomplish this by using generics ?

This is what i've done so far :

```
public class SortManager {
    public <T extends Collection> void bubbleSort(T collection) {
        //sort a given collection

    }

    public <T extends Collection<?>> boolean isSorted(T collection) {
        //need to check if a given collection is sorted
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
@Test
    public void testIfTheCollectionsAreSorted() {
        ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

        SortManager sortManager = new SortManager();
        sortManager.bubbleSort(integers);
        assertTrue(sortManager.isSorted(integers));
    }
```

Comment: Are you waiting for someone to provide the implementation?

Comment: Change method signatures to `<T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)`, `<T extends Comparable<? super T>> boolean isSorted(Iterable<T> collection)` to be able using `compareTo()` of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not sort any given collection, because not all collections are ordered. However, you can sort any `List<...>`

Bubble sort is easily looked up and implemented, what you missed here is that the elements must implement `Comparable<...>` or change the signature to take a comparator (but you probably want the latter)

```
class SortManager {
    public <T> void bubbleSort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> comp) {
        ...
    }

    public <T> boolean isSorted(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> comp) {
        ...
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: besides, `isSorted()` can be applied to `Collection` or even `Iterable`